# pytorch torch.jit.trace returns function instead of torch.jit.ScriptModule

Tags: python, c++, pytorch, libtorch

I need to run in c++ a pre-trained pytorch nn model (trained in python) to make predictions.

To do so, I'm following the instructions on how to load a pytorch model in c++ given here: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_export.html

But when I try to get the torch.jit.ScriptModule via tracing as stated in the first step of the tutorial:

```
    traced_script_module =
        torch.jit.trace(model, (input_tensor_1, input_tensor_2))
```

Instead of returning a torch.jit.ScriptModule, it returns a function:

```
    print(type(traced_script_module))
    <type 'function'>
```

Which, when I run:

```
    traced_script_module.save("model.pt")
```

then leads into the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serialize_model.py", line 60, in <module>
    traced_script_module.save("model.pt")
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your PyTorch version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for asking [Jatentaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4280242/jatentaki). I was using PyTorch 0.4 in Python and when I updated to 1.0 it worked.